# LSApplicationCategoryType key in WatchKit App is invalid

Tags: swift, xcode, watchos, watchos-4

I got the error "Invalid Info.plist key. The key 'LSApplicationCategoryType' in bundle NursingApp.app/Watch/NursingApp WatchKit App.app is invalid."

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW8 LSApplicationCategoryType is only supported on macOS, which I guess explains why it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

At first I tried adding an Application Category key to the info.plist of the watch app, the extensions, and the handset app, but these all failed too. In the end I just had to remove the key and everything worked after that.